# Google play throws a message (see below) when I try to upload signed app release .apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am trying to upload an app to Google play from the Google play developer console, and it throws the following message when I try to upload an apk file: "You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted." The package that my app's classes belong to is called com.example.myname.converter. What is the best way to fix the problem without messing things up?

Comment: remove **.example** from the package, refactor it to **com.myname.converter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android studio build gradle  file change the package name.

The defaultConfig  like this

```
applicationId "com.example.android.applicationname"
```

change that com.example package name

```
applicationId "com.yourcustomname.yourcustomname.applicationname"
```

then clean and rebuild project

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a valid `appId`. An `appId` like `com.example` is, for sure, not the correct one.

For instance, if you app is from `Facebook` an app id like `com.facebook.app` is the correct choice.

Se more information about the `appId` [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

For updating your app id, just go to your app `build.gradle` and change the field `applicationId`.